# failed to find protobuf header file

Tags: protobuf-c

I pod Protobuf-C++ in my ios app, but build failed, build error log looks like this

```
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  Protobuf-C++/src/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream.cc:35:10: fatal error: 'google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream.h' file not found
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  Protobuf-C++/src/google/protobuf/wrappers.pb.cc:4:10: fatal error: 'google/protobuf/wrappers.pb.h' file not found
```

anyone knonw how to fix this ? my protobuf version is 3.11.3

Answer (score 3):

[problem like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGC3q.png)

[image]

```
'google/protobuf/any.h' file not found
'google/protobuf/arena_test_util.h' file not found
'google/protobuf/util/delimited_message_util.h' file not found
```

maybe other file not found.
the way to fix it:

[image]

[way to fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRU8q.png)

```
1. select 'Pods'
2. select 'Protobuf-C++'
3. select 'Build Settings'
4. search 'search path'
5. select 'Header Search Paths'
6. add '$(SRCROOT)/Protobuf-C++/src'
```

Comment: It works for me，thanks a lot!  @Rome
i also checked podspec file of Protofbuf, it has missed this config but others does "xcconfig": 
{
  "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS": "$(PODS_ROOT)/SQLCipher",
   ......
}
which looks like same to your solution

Comment: Hi, after a `pod install`, I have to do the same thing again manually. Is there any ways to auto do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It works for me，thanks a lot!  @Rome
i also checked podspec file of Protofbuf, it has missed this config but others does "xcconfig":
{
"HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS": "$(PODS_ROOT)/SQLCipher",
......
}
which looks like same to your solution

Answer (score 0):

@Rome's solution is quite helpful, but after a pod install, I have to do the same thing again manually. So I try to improve it and with this solution, no extra work is needed.

Put the following code in your `Podfile`:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    # print "target=", target, "\n"
    if target.name == "Protobuf-C++"
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS'] = '$(SRCROOT)/Protobuf-C++/src'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In addition, if you have some C++ code that uses protobuf (i.e. includes it), you may also need to do the following in your `xxx.podspec`:

```
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(SRCROOT)/Protobuf-C++/src',
  }
```